# Integrating a PrimeFaces component into another

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I want to use this table http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/d ... tering.jsf but I want to replace the column year with two columns, debut date and end date. I don't want the user to manually enter the date he wants to fiter, instead I want him to click on the text are and then calendar show, basicaly, I want to use this https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml, the second popup one. Is that possible?

Comment: Just wrap the calendar component into the column.

Comment: @XtremeBiker: here is my column code
 <p:column id="dateDebutColumn" filterBy="#{rep.dateDebut}"  
                headerText="Date de début" footerText="startsWith">  
            <h:outputText value="#{rep.dateDebut}" 
                          id="popupDate">
              <f:convertDateTime pattern="d/M/yyyy"/>  
            </h:outputText>
            
        </p:column>
How can i wrap a clendar in there ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap whatever you want into your columns. You only need to bind variable values. There you have what you want in a simple way:

```
<p:column id="dateDebutColumn" filterBy="#{rep.dateDebut}" headerText="Date de début" footerText="startsWith"> 
    <h:outputText value="#{rep.dateDebut}" 
        id="popupDate"> 
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="d/M/yyyy" /> 
    </h:outputText>
    <p:calendar value="#{rep.dateDebut}" />
</p:column>
```

This will display your selected date and add a calendar object with that value by default.

Comment: @@XtremeBiker: I already did that but it's not what i want, cause i only want the calendar to apply on the filter input field, the rest of rows should't implement any text field, they only diplay content of rep.dateDebut, or if they implement it.

Comment: Then you'll need to add a calendar to a column header and [manage the filtering by your own](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10578). Sorry but I misunderstood your issue.